# How to generate coverage report for ES6 code with istanbul

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, tdd, istanbul

How can I get `istanbul` to generate coverage with ES6? I'm using jasmine for testing and I can get it to run ES6 code with

```
babel-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js tests/routes.js
```

But I can't use babel-node anywhere with istanbul

**package.json**

```
"test": "babel-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js tests/routes.js",
"coverage": "istanbul cover node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js"
```

Tests will not run if i run `npm run coverage` in the terminal because of import statements in my code. I cannot do

```
"coverage": "istanbul cover babel-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js"
```

I'll get nasty errors. I can get the coverage report to run somewhat by not using import statements in my tests. But I'll still get errors because I'm using import statements in the rest of my code. So how do I generate coverage report with istanbul for ES6 code?